# transform XML into one that can be imported into Access

Tags: xslt

I want to use XSLT to transform XML into one that can be imported into Access the input file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<DatosGen>
    <Vendedor>
        <Nombre>Juan Garcia Sanchez</Nombre>
        <Codigo>VE144</Codigo>
    </Vendedor>
    <Fecha>30-abr-2015</Fecha>
</DatosGen>
<Pedidos>
    <Pedido>
        <Cabecera>
            <Numero>34</Numero>
            <Fecha>28-abr-2015</Fecha>
            <Cliente>
                <Nombre>Antonio Lopez Martin</Nombre>
                <Codigo>CL121</Codigo>
            </Cliente>
            <Portes>SI</Portes>
        </Cabecera>
        <Detalle>
            <Linea>
                <Articulo>Ar654</Articulo>
                <Cantidad>12</Cantidad>
                <Precio>2</Precio>
            </Linea>
            <Linea>
                <Articulo>Ar670</Articulo>
                <Cantidad>9</Cantidad>
                <Precio>1.21</Precio>
            </Linea>
            <Linea>
                <Articulo>Ar100</Articulo>
                <Cantidad>2</Cantidad>
                <Precio>3.45</Precio>
            </Linea>
            <Linea>
                <Articulo>Ar999</Articulo>
                <Cantidad>215</Cantidad>
                <Precio>12.24</Precio>
            </Linea>                
        </Detalle>
    </Pedido>
    <Pedido>
        <Cabecera>
            <Numero>35</Numero>
            <Fecha>29-abr-2015</Fecha>
            <Cliente>
                <Nombre>Manuel Enriquez Sousa</Nombre>
                <Codigo>CL160</Codigo>
            </Cliente>
            <Portes>NO</Portes>
        </Cabecera>
        <Detalle>
            <Linea>
                <Articulo>Ar003</Articulo>
                <Cantidad>10</Cantidad>
                <Precio>2.21</Precio>
            </Linea>
            <Linea>
                <Articulo>Ar005</Articulo>
                <Cantidad>8</Cantidad>
                <Precio>1.28</Precio>
            </Linea>
            <Linea>
                <Articulo>Ar100</Articulo>
                <Cantidad>5</Cantidad>
                <Precio>3.75</Precio>
            </Linea>
        </Detalle>
    </Pedido>
</Pedidos>
</Document>
```

Is Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot generated="2015-08-22T13:10:05" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
<importarxml>
    <Vendedor>Juan Garcia Sanchez</Vendedor>
    <idVendedor>VE144</idVendedor>
    <FechaFichero>30-abr-2015</FechaFichero>
    <Pedido>34</Pedido>
    <Fecha>28-abr-2015</Fecha>
    <Cliente>Antonio Lopez Martin</Cliente>
    <idCliente>CL121</idCliente>
    <Portes>SI</Portes>
    <Articulo>Ar100</Articulo>
    <Cantidad>5</Cantidad>
    <Precio>3.75</Precio>
</importarxml>
<importarxml>
    <Vendedor>Juan Garcia Sanchez</Vendedor>
    <idVendedor>VE144</idVendedor>
    <FechaFichero>30-abr-2015</FechaFichero>
    <Pedido>34</Pedido>
    <Fecha>28-abr-2015</Fecha>
    <Cliente>Antonio Lopez Martin</Cliente>
    <idCliente>CL121</idCliente>
    <Portes>SI</Portes>
    <Articulo>Ar005</Articulo>
    <Cantidad>8</Cantidad>
    <Precio>1.28</Precio>
</importarxml>
<importarxml>
    <Vendedor>Juan Garcia Sanchez</Vendedor>
    <idVendedor>VE144</idVendedor>
    <FechaFichero>30-abr-2015</FechaFichero>
    <Pedido>34</Pedido>
    <Fecha>28-abr-2015</Fecha>
    <Cliente>Antonio Lopez Martin</Cliente>
    <idCliente>CL121</idCliente>
    <Portes>SI</Portes>
    <Articulo>Ar003</Articulo>
    <Cantidad>10</Cantidad>
    <Precio>2.21</Precio>
</importarxml>
<importarxml>
    <Vendedor>Juan Garcia Sanchez</Vendedor>
    <idVendedor>VE144</idVendedor>
    <FechaFichero>30-abr-2015</FechaFichero>
    <Pedido>34</Pedido>
    <Fecha>28-abr-2015</Fecha>
    <Cliente>Antonio Lopez Martin</Cliente>
    <idCliente>CL121</idCliente>
    <Portes>SI</Portes>
    <Articulo>Ar999</Articulo>
    <Cantidad>215</Cantidad>
    <Precio>12.24</Precio>
</importarxml>
<importarxml>
    <Vendedor>Juan Garcia Sanchez</Vendedor>
    <idVendedor>VE144</idVendedor>
    <FechaFichero>30-abr-2015</FechaFichero>
    <Pedido>35</Pedido>
    <Fecha>29-abr-2015</Fecha>
    <Cliente>Manuel Enriquez Sousa</Cliente>
    <idCliente>CL160</idCliente>
    <Portes>No</Portes>
    <Articulo>Ar100</Articulo>
    <Cantidad>2</Cantidad>
    <Precio>3.45</Precio>
</importarxml>
<importarxml>
    <Vendedor>Juan Garcia Sanchez</Vendedor>
    <idVendedor>VE144</idVendedor>
    <FechaFichero>30-abr-2015</FechaFichero>
    <Pedido>35</Pedido>
    <Fecha>29-abr-2015</Fecha>
    <Cliente>Manuel Enriquez Sousa</Cliente>
    <idCliente>CL160</idCliente>
    <Portes>No</Portes>
    <Articulo>Ar670</Articulo>
    <Cantidad>9</Cantidad>
    <Precio>1.21</Precio>
</importarxml>
<importarxml>
    <Vendedor>Juan Garcia Sanchez</Vendedor>
    <idVendedor>VE144</idVendedor>
    <FechaFichero>30-abr-2015</FechaFichero>
    <Pedido>35</Pedido>
    <Fecha>29-abr-2015</Fecha>
    <Cliente>Manuel Enriquez Sousa</Cliente>
    <idCliente>CL160</idCliente>
    <Portes>No</Portes>
    <Articulo>Ar654</Articulo>
    <Cantidad>12</Cantidad>
    <Precio>2</Precio>
</importarxml>
</dataroot>
```

My xslt not work in Pedido Fecha y Cliente:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2015-08-22T13:10:05">
      <xsl:for-each select="//Document/Pedidos/Pedido/Detalle/Linea">
        <xsl:sort select="//Cliente/Nombre" order="descending" />
        <importarxml>
          <Vendedor>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Vendedor/Nombre" />
          </Vendedor>
          <idVendedor>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Vendedor/Codigo" />
          </idVendedor>
          <FechaFichero>
            <xsl:value-of select="//DatosGen/Fecha" />
          </FechaFichero>
          <Pedido>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Cabecera/Numero" />
          </Pedido>
          <Fecha>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Cabecera/Fecha" />
          </Fecha>
          <Cliente>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Cabecera/Cliente/Nombre" />
          </Cliente>
          <idCliente>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Cabecera/Cliente/Codigo" />
          </idCliente>
          <Portes>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Cabecera/Portes" />
          </Portes>
          <Articulo>
            <xsl:value-of select="Articulo" />
          </Articulo>
          <Cantidad>
            <xsl:value-of select="Cantidad" />
          </Cantidad>
          <Precio>
            <xsl:value-of select="Precio" />
          </Precio>
        </importarxml>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </dataroot>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you explain what doe *not work*? Please include the desired output.

Comment: The desired output is what I put.
 The mistake is that I repeat data from the first client ever, but the content is correct node Linea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have your XPath references correct.

Inside your `<xsl:for-each>`, all paths are relative to the `<Linea>` nodes, unless you write absolute paths (paths starting with a `/`). This is also your main mistake: Absolute paths have no context, therefore they select different nodes than you might want.

To access the vendor name with a relative path it would be required to go up four levels first:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../../DatosGen/Vendedor/Nombre" />
```

Since this is difficult to follow, it's clearer to use the `ancestor` axis:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Document[1]/DatosGen/Vendedor/Nombre" />
```

But of course there is only one `<DatosGen>` in your input, so you could use absolute paths as well:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Document/DatosGen/Vendedor/Nombre" />
```

Either way, you need that more than once, so you can create and use a variable, like here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/Document">
    <dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2015-08-22T13:10:05">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Pedidos/Pedido/Detalle/Linea">
            <xsl:sort select="Cabecera/Cliente/Nombre" order="descending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </dataroot>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Linea">
    <xsl:variable name="DatosGen" select="ancestor::Document[1]/DatosGen" />
    <xsl:variable name="Cabecera" select="ancestor::Pedido[1]/Cabecera" />
    <importarxml>
      <Vendedor><xsl:value-of select="$DatosGen/Vendedor/Nombre" /></Vendedor>
      <idVendedor><xsl:value-of select="$DatosGen/Vendedor/Codigo" /></idVendedor>
      <FechaFichero><xsl:value-of select="$DatosGen/Fecha" /></FechaFichero>
      <Pedido><xsl:value-of select="$Cabecera/Numero" /></Pedido>
      <Fecha><xsl:value-of select="$Cabecera/Fecha" /></Fecha>
      <Cliente><xsl:value-of select="$Cabecera/Cliente/Nombre" /></Cliente>
      <idCliente><xsl:value-of select="$Cabecera/Cliente/Codigo" /></idCliente>
      <Portes><xsl:value-of select="$Cabecera/Portes" /></Portes>
      <Articulo><xsl:value-of select="Articulo" /></Articulo>
      <Cantidad><xsl:value-of select="Cantidad" /></Cantidad>
      <Precio><xsl:value-of select="Precio" /></Precio>
    </importarxml>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You leave me amazed at your ease, I was looking for the key function and also for the axes, but it was not clear where to start and auque him and taken many turns to examples found nothing similar. I study variables and axes, thank you.